# How can I apply a function to every argument of another function?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that takes 10 `String` parameters and during some refactoring, portions of the code have changed so now these parameters end up as `Text` when the function is called:

```
fxn :: String -> ... -> IO (Int, String)
fxn a b c d e f g h i j = do something 

...

-- Get parameters for fxn
let a = "blah" :: Text
...
fxn a b c ...
```

Ideally, I could refactor all of the code to use `Text`, but that is tedious and non ideal currently. I could also easily add a `T.unpack` to where I get the parameters for my function:

```
let a = T.unpack ("blah" :: Text)
```

But again, this is non ideal since this happens in several different places for large numbers of arguments and I'd prefer to keep the code cleaner than having dozens of `T.unpack` statements everywhere.

Is there a way in haskell to either compose the functions so that the arguments are morphed, something like `(fxn . T.unpack) a b c ...`, or to apply the unpack function to every argument of the f function? This seems like a simple composition problem but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: 10 parameters?! that seems a bit excessive, you should definitely refactor... regarding your question: can you provide the type of the function you're looking for?

Comment: It seems excessive but it's a server and dealing with JSON parameters so it's most likely only going to grow unfortunately. I can't find a better way to manage that portion of the code. I can definitely provide type signatures, which function did you mean though?

Comment: If you change your code to use `Text` in one place but leave `String` everywhere else, then you 1. get the problem you've run into, and 2. lose all hope of performance improvements. This is not a Haskell issue - this is a design issue. Use Text or String uniformly, or have an overloaded version of your function which operators on both types (this kills type inference), or don't use 10 string parameters so you don't incur the cost of adding `T.unpack` 10 times over.

Comment: @user2407038 I'm not using `Text` for the performance, this section of code interfaces between two systems. One needs `String`, one needs `Text` for various reasons. I'm just asking about the generic here about applying a function to another functions arguments.

Comment: What about using [Data.String](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-String.html) wouldn't that be useful, to abstract the "stringyness" oft the parameters.

Comment: @jkeuhlen If you really must, you can write a function like `Data.Function.on`, but for 10 parameters - however, this is little improvement over simply defining a new function as @Daniel Wagner suggested. If you make your ten parameters into a record (i.e. fix the design issues in your program) then write a function e.g. `mapOpts :: (a -> b) -> Opts a -> Opts b` then the solution to your problem is simply function composition - `fxn . mapOpts T.unpack`. Writing a polyvariadic `on` function is fairly easy, but your problem has a *trivial* solution if you just fix the design issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For dealing with the parameter proliferation, you may like the [record parameter](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/haskell-anti-pattern-incremental-ad-hoc-parameter-abstraction/) pattern. This also makes it convenient to expose a new API with the same name while maintaining backwards compatibility.

For the question as asked, it's usually simplest to define a short adapter like this:

```
fxnNew :: Text -> ... -> IO (Int, Text)
fxnNew = ...

fxn :: String -> ... -> IO (Int, String)
fxn a ... i = fmap (fmap T.unpack) (fxnNew (T.pack a) ... (T.pack i))
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's pretty helpful. This looks slightly cleaner but I was hoping to avoid defining new functions just for this transformation. Either way, thanks for the input!